# Breakpoint Is Not Getting Hooked in Eclipse with GWT Application

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt

I am trying to debug a very simple HTML GWT module in *Eclipse*, but the breakpoint in my `EntryPoint` class does not get hit! I have the following setup:

- GWT version: 2.7
- Eclipse version: Mars 4.5.2
- Chrome version: 53
- Running mode: Super Dev Mode (debug)

My module contains a simple HTML file with one `EntryPoint` (It's a proverbial HelloWorld). The application starts normally when I do *Run As Super Dev Mode* or *Debug As Super Dev Mode*, and I see server's and client's URL's and ports with no errors. I can navigate to the application's HTML URL to see the simple Label, and even recompile and see the changes if I modify the `EntryPoint` class which contains the Label.

I have set my argument's log level to *DEBUG* (see tons of loading various modules) and even check marked Debug As Configuration to stop at the main method. The thing is, when I run the application in *Debug Super Dev Mode* for the first time to start the core server, I can see the breakpoint stopping in `DevMode` class' `main()` method (not afterward though when I make changes to the `EntryPoint` and recompile by refreshing the browser). But when I set a breakpoint in my `EntryPoint`'s `onModuleLoad()`, it gets ignored!

How can I get the server to put a hook on my `EntryPoint`?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases there is no code available for a JavaScript statement.

Try to use:

```
GWT.debugger();
```

which will always stops if you are using a debugger.

Comment: Do you really need to include that method call? I can simply go to Chrome's Source tab in `Developer tools` and put a breakpoint in the *sourcemap* class loaded on the code server.

Comment: Even in Google Chrome, there might be breakpoints, the debugger will not stop. The only way to make sure, that the debugger stops is to use GWT.debugger(); This generates a JavaScript statement "debugger();", which forces the application to stop in debug mode. In production mode, debugger statements are ignored.

Comment: Can you please describe more about where should I put this command?

Comment: Just add it to your source, best before the statement you want to debug.

Comment: I put it right after the onModuleLoad is on. It seems stopping at every breakpoints. Good. But is there anything to do with the real production version?

Comment: You should remove the statement once you don't need it anymore. But even if you forgot it, it doesn't matter. GWT.debugger() is ignore when compiling for production.